# Codename One: ComponentGroupBool on Android by CSS

Tags: codenameone

*Note for the readers: this question is specific for Codename One only.*

The following code works perfectly on iOS:

```
    ComponentGroup cmpGroup = ComponentGroup.enclose(camera, gallery);
    cmpGroup.getComponentAt(0).getAllStyles().setAlignment(Component.LEFT);
    cmpGroup.getComponentAt(1).getAllStyles().setAlignment(Component.LEFT);
```

with this CSS:

```
#Constants {
    ComponentGroupBool: true;
    includeNativeBool: true;
    [...]
}
```

The problem is that there is no effect on Android.
So, I understood that the `CompontGroup` UIIDs are implemented in the iOS native theme, but they are not in the Android native theme.

My question is how to make the `CompontGroup` working in the same way on iOS and Android, using CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add styles for `GroupElementFirst`, `GroupElementLast`, `GroupElement`, `GroupElementOnly`, `ButtonGroupFirst`, `ButtonGroupLast`, `ButtonGroup`, `ButtonGroupOnly`.

Styling ButtonGroup* would let you avoid the alignment left styling you have in your code.

We designed the round rect borders top/bottom only modes exactly for this purpose but I'm not sure if they are implemented in CSS. I'll have to check on that.

Comment: Do you think that this CSS code can be improved? https://stackoverflow.com/a/52179262/2670744

Comment: I think the CSS implementation can be improved, right now images are generated for CSS of this type instead of the `RoundRectBorder` we need to fix that.

Answer (score 1):

A possible (not pixel-perfect) solution based on the [Shai's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52177045/2670744), that produces an acceptable result like this:

[image]

It's not pixel-perfect because between the `GroupElementFirst` and the `GroupElementLast` there is a small space.

```
/* Start of ComponentGroup CSS */

GroupElementFirst {
    border-width: 0.3mm;
    border-color: gray;
    border-style: solid;
    border-top-right-radius: 3mm;
    border-top-left-radius: 3mm;
    margin: 2mm;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    padding: 2mm;
}

GroupElementLast{
    border-width: 0.3mm;
    border-color: gray;
    border-style: solid;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 3mm;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 3mm;
    margin: 2mm;
    margin-top: 0px;
    padding: 2mm;
}

GroupElement{
    border-width: 0.3mm;
    border-color: gray;
    border-style: solid;
    margin: 2mm;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    padding: 2mm;
}

GroupElementOnly{
    border-width: 0.3mm;
    border-color: gray;
    border-style: solid;
    border-radius: 3mm;
    margin: 2mm;
    padding: 2mm;
}

ButtonGroupFirst{
    cn1-derive: GroupElementFirst;
}

ButtonGroupLast{
    cn1-derive: GroupElementLast;
}

ButtonGroup{
    cn1-derive: GroupElement;
}

ButtonGroupOnly {
    cn1-derive: GroupElementOnly;
}

/* End of ComponentGroup */
```